# How to speed up large copy into a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to load a large dataset (25 GB) into a Postgres table. The command below works, but it takes 2.5 hours and fully utilizes 3-4 cores on the machine the entire time. Can I speed it up a lot? The problem is I want to insert another 1700 such 25 GB files into the table too (these would be separate partitions). 2.5 hours per file is too slow. Or rather it's not too slow, but makes me think subsequent queries against the data will be too slow.

Probably my dataset is too big for Postgres, but the idea of being able to run an optimized query (once the data is all inserted and later indexed and partitioned) and get a result back in < 3 seconds is appealing, hence I wanted to try.

I'm mostly following the guidelines from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html). I don't have an index on the table yet. I don't use foreign keys, I'm using a bulk `copy`, etc.

```
-- some of the numeric columns have "nan" values so they need to start as strings in raw form
CREATE TABLE raw_eqtl_allpairs (
  gene_id varchar,
    variant_id varchar,
    chr varchar,
    bp BIGINT,
    ref_ varchar,
    alt varchar,
    tss_distance bigint,
    ma_samples int,
    ma_count int,
    maf varchar,
    pval_nominal varchar,
    slope varchar,
    slope_se varchar,
    chromosome_ varchar,
    pos BIGINT,
    af varchar
);

COPY raw_eqtl_allpairs(gene_id, variant_id, chr, bp, ref_, alt, tss_distance, ma_samples, ma_count, maf, pval_nominal, slope, slope_se, chromosome_, pos, af)
FROM '/Downloads/genomics_data.tsv'
DELIMITER E'\t'
CSV HEADER;
```

**Edit 1:**
I'm running on Docker on my Mac, which has 4 Intel i7 cores and 16 GB of ram. I have 500 GB of flash storage.

**Edit 2:**
I'm using the default `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` that comes with the DockerHub Postgres `14.2` [tag](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e8ebf74e50128123a8d0220b85e357ef2d73a7ec/14/bullseye/Dockerfile). For simplicity, I grepped it for key details. Seems like most of the important things were commented out:

```
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB        # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1       # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
max_wal_size = 1GB
#wal_level = replica            # minimal, replica, or logical
#checkpoint_timeout = 5min      # range 30s-1d
#archive_mode = off     # enables archiving; off, on, or always
#max_wal_senders = 10       # max number of walsender processes
```

Maybe I could speed things up a lot if I changed `wal_level` to `minimal`, and changed `max_wal_size` to something larger, like `4GB`?

Comment: To your question add the machine specifications e.g. memory, disk type, processor, etc. Also, the relevant settings in `postgresql.conf`. Given that folks are terabyte and petabyte instances of Postgres, I don't see the data set as being too big.

Comment: Which lines of `postgresql.conf` are the most relevant? I'm not familiar with that file. I was able to find it, but it's 800 lines.

Comment: The ones mentioned in the link you posted. You might also want to look at the Postgres log when you do this to see if it throwing warnings.

Comment: With 500GB of storage, you will never get 1700 files of 25GB on that disk.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I agree. The total data size is 1-5 TB. I'm just doing a POC with a few of the files on my laptop. If I can confirm it works well enough on my laptop for a few files, I'll set up a proper DB in AWS with sufficient storage and other appropriate specs.

Comment: "Or rather it's not too slow, but makes me think subsequent queries against the data will be too slow."  There is no logical connection between those two things.  You might as well tune your database with a Ouija board.

Comment: You can use pgtune to help you get started with configuration params https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/ Use the data warehouse db type for your bulk import use case.